# Convert color video to grayscale video in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to do some operations on color video in MATLAB however, I am facing 2 problems:

- I am getting an error while converting color video to grayscale video. I mean I need to convert color video to grayscale video and write it back to .avi file
- How can I perform some operation (say edge detection) on grayscale frames (extracted from color video) and then can write back the result of edge detection in .avi video format?

My incomplete code (which consist of color format conversion) is as follows:

```
vid = VideoReader('Big_buck_bunny_480p_Cut.avi');
numImgs = get(vid, 'NumberOfFrames');
frames = read(vid);
for i=1:numImgs
  frames(:,:,:,i)=rgb2gray(frames(:,:,:,i));
end
```

Any pointer to fix these two problems?

Comment: why not use a different frame to save a grayscale video, say `frame1`. Then each for loop save `frame1` using `[writeVideo](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.writevideo.html)`. Second option is create an array of grayscale frames and write it using `writeVideo`. In the latter, you have to create a 3-D array and not 4-D. For example, `frames1(:,:,i)=rgb2gray(frames(:,:,:,i));`.

Answer (score 4):

Your first problem is due to trying to assign the 2D output of rgb2gray into a 3D array. You can fix this by converting the gray image back to RGB format:

```
  frames(:,:,:,i)=repmat(rgb2gray(frames(:,:,:,i)),[1 1 3]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
%% convert a RGB video to a grayscale one.
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('xylophone.mpg');
videoFWriter = vision.VideoFileWriter('xylophone_gray.avi',...
   'FrameRate',videoFReader.info.VideoFrameRate);
while ~isDone(videoFReader)
   videoFrame = step(videoFReader);
   step(videoFWriter, rgb2gray(videoFrame));
end
release(videoFReader);
release(videoFWriter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way. This should do the trick. The code is self-explanatory.

```
 vid = VideoReader('xylophone.mpg');
 numImgs = get(vid, 'NumberOfFrames');
 frames = read(vid);
 obj=VideoWriter('somefile.avi');
 open(obj);

 for i=1:numImgs
     movie(i).cdata=rgb2gray(frames(:,:,:,i));
     movie(i).colormap=gray;
 end

 writeVideo(obj,movie);
 close(obj);
```