# Convert video into greyscale in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to convert a video file into greyscale. When I try running the Matlab script I get a "Invalid video data-must be a numeric or logical data type". Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong? I am also new to matlab.

```
filename = 'Project1.m4v'; 
vid = VideoReader(filename); 
newVid = VideoWriter('NewVid');

open(newVid);
numFrames = vid.NumberOfFrames;
for frame = 1 : numFrames
    % Extract the frame from the movie structure.
    thisFrame = read(vid, frame); 
    %Convert each frame to black and white
    gray = rgb2gray(thisFrame); 
    writeVideo(newVid,gray); 

end

close(newVid); 

implay(newVid);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert color video to grayscale video in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306581/convert-color-video-to-grayscale-video-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `implay('NewVid.avi')` instead of `implay(newVid);`

The only problem in your code is the last line: `implay(newVid);`.
`newVid` is a `VideoWriter` object - you create it using `newVid = VideoWriter('NewVid');`.

I recommend you to add `'.avi'` file extension to `'NewVid'` file name:
Use: `newVid = VideoWriter('NewVid.avi');`

`implay` does't take `VideoWriter` object as input parameter.
Instead of displaying an error message in Matlab workspace, it displays the error message in the video window.

All you need to do, is replacing last code line with `implay('NewVid.avi')`.

[image]