# How to create a grayscale video

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I wrote a code in Matlab, in which I have to read a color video, retrieve the frames from the video perform some operations with the frames and then again make a video from the operated frames i wrote a simple code for converting each frame to gray-scale and thus generating the gray-scale video and it showed the following error:

> Warning: No video frames were written to this file. The file may b invalid.
>
> In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.close at 307
>
> In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.delete at 256
>
> In getFrames2Image at 9

Following is the code i wrote

```
a=VideoReader('test.mp4');
images=cell(a.NumberOfFrames,1);
for img=1:a.NumberOfFrames
    b=read(a,img);
    c=rgb2gray(b);
    images{img}=b;
end
outp=VideoWriter('output');
outp.FrameRate=30;
open(outp);
for i=1:length(images)
    frame=im2frame(images{i});
    writeVideo(outp,frame);
end
close(outp);
```

As requested here are the details of my matlab version:
Matlab R2013a(8.1.0.604)
64 bit(win64)
and link of the sample video
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-MZ8myQc4ZKU0E1dURPRUhwd1k

Comment: Here are some answers of doing that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306581/convert-color-video-to-grayscale-video-in-matlab

Comment: The file you're using may not be compatible with the codecs that work with MATLAB on your operating system. Please include the operating system, version of MATLAB you're using as well as a link to the video you are using to perform this conversion so we can further assist.

Comment: @rayryeng i have updated the details